# Custom waypoint function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Hello I am writing a custom waypoint function and I am getting an error and was wondering if someone could help me out. The function is using waypoints.js

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Here is the code I have so far

```
var waypoint = function(triggerElement, animatedElement, className, offsetVal) {
    element: document.getElementById(triggerElement);
    handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            animatedElement.addClass(className);
            this.destroy();
        }
        else {

        }
    };
    offset: offsetVal;
};

//Trigger Elements
var section2 = jQuery('#section-2');

//Waypoint Instances
waypoint(section2, "section-2-orange-dot", "section-2-orange-dot-active", 500);
```

I am getting an error at the third line

`handler: function(direction) {`

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use commas to delimit the function arguments, not semicolons. You are also passing in the selected jQuery object as triggerElement, so you don't need the getElementById:

```
function waypoint (triggerElement, animatedElement, className, offsetVal)
{
    return new Waypoint({ 
        element: triggerElement,
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'down') {
                animatedElement.addClass(className);
                this.destroy();
            }
        },
        offset: offsetVal
    });
}
```

Comment: awesome thank you, i will try this out and if it works ill accept as answer

Comment: Is the basic gist of it. You can probably avoid the wrapper "waypoint" function and just call the new Waypoint({... directly in your code if you have the arguments available in script. good luck